# NFC, is it possible to exchange strings or bytes between Android and Windows phone?

Tags: android, windows-phone, arduino, nfc

I need to create an Android app that comunicates (send a string or bytes) with a Windows Phone app, with NFC. Is it possible? How can I do it without bluetooth?

How to connect (android and Windows phone) to arduino UNO with a NFC Shield (http://www.adafruit.com/product/789)?

I want to create apps in C# and Java.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://linksprite.com/wiki/index.php5?title=NFC_PN532_Shield#Quick_Start_Demo) is a wiki that explains the API of this Adafruit NFC shield. In a section, `Demo 2: PtoPInitiator.pde and PtoPTarget.ino`, An example is shown and it seems that the Peer-to-Peer communication is available for use.

I have never touched Windows Phone so I don't know that it is available now but, [here](http://www.slideshare.net/andreasjakl/windows-8-platform-nfc-development) is a explanation for using NFC (as well as Peer-to-Peer) on Windows Phone 8.

The way to use Peer-to-Peer communication on Android is already asked / answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803373/how-to-do-nfc-peer-to-peer-connection-in-android).